# posting a php GD processed image or something else when user clicks a button in facebook application

Tags: php, facebook

how to post something on user wall ( may be a php processed image or something text ) when user clicks a button. As an example suppose a facebook user installs my  app, then it shows some processed image then if the user wishes to publish he clicks the publish button and get published to his wall otherwise it will not. The difficulty I faced is to to go from one page to another ( as going from index.php to upload.php) ,transferring **access_token**,and how to make api call to upload the image from upload.php should i have to make upload.php as index.php so as it can re authenticate the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sound really confused.

There should be no difference if you name your file `index.php`or `upload.php`.

I don't see why you would need to manually take care of the access token. Use the PHP SDK, and it is done automatically for you. The PHP SDK uses the `$_SESSION` variable to store it. Otherwise, you could pass it in the URL as an argument like:

```
upload.php?access_token=SOMETHING_REALLY_SECRET
```

I'd not recommend that though, since it makes your site very vulnerable to attacks.

There is a complete example in the [PHP SDK documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/):

```
<?
  // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
  // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
    'fileUpload' => true,
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

  $photo = './mypic.png'; // Path to the photo on the local filesystem
  $message = 'Photo upload via the PHP SDK!';
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        // Upload to a user's profile. The photo will be in the
        // first album in the profile. You can also upload to
        // a specific album by using /ALBUM_ID as the path 
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
                                         'source' => '@' . $photo,
                                         'message' => $message,
                                         )
                                      );
        echo '<pre>Photo ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                       'scope' => 'photo_upload'
                       )); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   

      echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      // To upload a photo to a user's wall, we need photo_upload  permission
      // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
      // need to specify it here.
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'photo_upload') );
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```